# Question related to javascript's var keyword

Tags: javascript, scope

Does anyone know why the last alert in the code below complains that a is undefined. Shouldn't a is 11 because it's initialized in four() without using the var keyword? Thanks.

```
function three() {
  var a = 12
  function four() {
    a = 11
    function five() {
      alert(a)
    }
    return five
  }
  return four
}
three()()()
alert(a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because a has been declared with "var", the assignment to a in four() refers to that declared variable, and the scope of a is limited to three().

Answer (score 1):

`var a` is in local scope of function `three()`

Answer (score 0):

The last alert complains about a being undefined because of a **scope issue**. Since a was declared within a function, the last line(your alert statement) has absolutely no idea about a.

Answer (score 0):

```
function three() {
    var a = 12
    function four() {
        a = 11
        function five() {
             alert(a)
         }
    return five
    }
return four
}
three()()()
alert(a)
```

Simply put, a isn't defined because well, it isn't defined.

You don't have a variable a outside of your functions.  To grossly simplify it, things inside a set of curlies don't exist outside that set of curlies.

You could define it before the function or pass it into the function to fix this

```
function three() {
    a = 12
    function four() {
        a = 11
        function five() {
             alert(a)
         }
    return five
    }
return four
}
three()()()
alert(a)
```

Edit for comment:
[Variables declared without var are always global](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp), so getting rid of the var in 3 would do that.

Comment: If I change var a = 12 to a = 12 inside three() then it works. Why is that?

Comment: Variables declared without var are always global scope

Answer (score 0):

Also, since we're on the topic of scope in JS, I'd like to point out that there is no block-scope in JavaScript, only function and global. Anytime you skip the `var`, the declaration is effectively global. This catches a lot of people off-guard.

Comment: ok if that's the case, why shouldn't a is 11 since it is initialized without var?

Comment: Looks like this is late but I'll put it in here anyway - Like Ernest Friedman-Hill answered, when `a` is not found declared in the scope of `four`, the enclosing scope is checked and `a` is found in the scope of `three`. If, however, you'd used `a` without `var` in `three`, you'd see the behavior you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Since variable `a` is in the local scope of function `three` you are getting undefined.

This should give the value  of `a`

```
function three() 
{
    var a = 12;
    function four() {
        a = 11;
        function five() {
            return a;
        }
        return five;
    }
    return four;
}

var b = three()()();
alert(b);
```